# My datagridview ins't showing my data

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that I am populating from a class library in C#.  I populate the GridView by calling a method, FetchEmployee() in my EmployeeDataAccess class which returns a DataTable(dt). I have set the class as the BindingSource for this DataGridView. However, the DataGridView is only populating the first and last columns with data.  The middle columns are blank. This is the Binding Method:

```
private void dgvEmployeeBindGrid()
    {
        dgvEmployee.DataSource = null;
        dgvEmployee.DataSource = EmployeeDataAccess.FetchEmployees();
    }
```

This is the FetchEmployee() method:

```
public static DataTable FetchEmployees()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DatabaseConnection.Test))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "Employee_Fetch";
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    using (dt)
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                    }
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
```

Basically, the stored procedure just says "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE"

My results show the following:

EmpID with a value, the next three columns (Initials, FName, LName) all blank and the last column, Active is displaying the appropriate check for active or not checked for inactive.

Sorry, I did not know how to insert a screen shot. Can anyone give me some insight as to why the middle rows have been omitted?

Comment: Those columns that were omitted actually have data in them in your DatabaseConnection.Test connection, correct?

Comment: Yes.  All of the 24 columns show the EmpID and the Active columns in the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this error by renaming my public properties and private fields to exactly match the SQL data table fields I was referring to.  I am happy again :)